# OpenGL Stencil Buffer Error

Tags: opengl, buffer

I have a problem with a project based on OpenGL. 
There is a venue I'm trying to make in OpenGL- The Cathedral Of Brasilia.

This is how the project looks like when compiled on my PC: 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-GCSmyi_XkQ

This is how the project looks like when compiled on any other PC: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CsFVv9jmosg

This is the main code:

```
float a=0;
while(!glfwGetKey(GLFW_KEY_ESC) && glfwGetWindowParam(GLFW_OPENED))
{
    glClearColor(0.8,0.8,1,1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT+GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT+GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);


    glPushMatrix();

    gluLookAt(9*cos(a), 9*sin(a),4+6*sin(a), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); 
    a+=0.006; 

    glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);

    glColorMask(0, 0, 0, 0);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 1, 1);
    glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_REPLACE);
    draw_water();

    glColorMask(1, 1, 1, 1);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glStencilFunc(GL_EQUAL, 1, 1);
    glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP);

    glPushMatrix();
    glScalef(1, 1, -1.5);
    draw_venues_and_sky();
    glPopMatrix();

    glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glColor4ub(150, 150, 255, 100);
    draw_water();
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);

    draw_venues_and_sky();

    glPopMatrix();
    glfwSwapBuffers();
}
```

I guess there must be something wrong with the Stencil Buffer, but I do not know what.

Comment: im not sure about others, but i dont see your second video.

Comment: You really should not use arithmetic addition to manipulate a bitmask.

Comment: this and i would also check the glGetError() status and the fact if your context has a stencil buffer at all.

Comment: I figured it out! The problem was that the Stencil_Buffer_Bits on my OpenWindow was set to 0... I changed it to 8 and it works quite fine now! Thanks for the answers!